# JavaMail: Read Email on Ubuntu

Tags: java, linux, email, ubuntu, jakarta-mail

I have email on my Ubuntu box coming into a directory like /var/mail. In there is a file called "root" that contains all received emails. I use the "mail" command to access these emails in a more user-friendly way. Is there any way to configure JavaMail to read these emails without having to parse the "root" email file like a text file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaMail can parse the Unix mail file for you using the ["mbox" provider](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/MboxStore).

Answer (score -1):

The code below from http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javamail_api/javamail_api_checking_emails.htm reads email from POP3 account.

```
package com.tutorialspoint;

import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.Folder;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.NoSuchProviderException;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Store;

public class CheckingMails {

   public static void check(String host, String storeType, String user,
      String password) 
   {
      try {

      //create properties field
      Properties properties = new Properties();

      properties.put("mail.pop3.host", host);
      properties.put("mail.pop3.port", "995");
      properties.put("mail.pop3.starttls.enable", "true");
      Session emailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);

      //create the POP3 store object and connect with the pop server
      Store store = emailSession.getStore("pop3s");

      store.connect(host, user, password);

      //create the folder object and open it
      Folder emailFolder = store.getFolder("INBOX");
      emailFolder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);

      // retrieve the messages from the folder in an array and print it
      Message[] messages = emailFolder.getMessages();
      System.out.println("messages.length---" + messages.length);

      for (int i = 0, n = messages.length; i < n; i++) {
         Message message = messages[i];
         System.out.println("---------------------------------");
         System.out.println("Email Number " + (i + 1));
         System.out.println("Subject: " + message.getSubject());
         System.out.println("From: " + message.getFrom()[0]);
         System.out.println("Text: " + message.getContent().toString());

      }

      //close the store and folder objects
      emailFolder.close(false);
      store.close();

      } catch (NoSuchProviderException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (MessagingException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {

      String host = "pop.gmail.com";// change accordingly
      String mailStoreType = "pop3";
      String username = "yourmail@gmail.com";// change accordingly
      String password = "*****";// change accordingly

      check(host, mailStoreType, username, password);

   }

}
```

Comment: why the down vote?   something wrong with the snippet?